# Unhandled exception in push_back("constructor");

Tags: c++, memory, struct

Edit:Solved

> Unhandled exception at 0x00F25625 in Win32Project2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Thats my problem. I use MS Visual Studio Express 2012.

This error is throwed by this line

```
for(int i=1;i<maxLevel;i++)
    korona.push_back(Level(this,ratio*korona[i-1].l,i));
```

Thats korona declaration.

```
std::vector <Level> korona;
```

And "level" class:

```
class Level{
    public:
    float l;
    float color[3];
    char lvl;
    std::vector <Stick> sticks;
    Tree *S;
    Level(Tree *S,float l);
    Level(Tree *S,float l,char lvl);
    ~Level();

    void Change(float h);
};
```

And at the end Level constructor:

```
Level::Level(Tree *S,float l,char lvl){

    this->l=l;
    this->lvl=lvl;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        this->color[i]=0.0;
    this->S=S;
    //sticks.resize(S->amount*S->korona[lvl-1].sticks.size());
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<S->korona[lvl-1].sticks.size();i++){
        float x=S->korona[lvl-1].sticks[i].x;
        float Sx=S->korona[lvl-1].sticks[i].S->x;
        float y=S->korona[lvl-1].sticks[i].y;
        float Sy=S->korona[lvl-1].sticks[i].S->y;
        float z=S->korona[lvl-1].sticks[i].z;
        float Sz=S->korona[lvl-1].sticks[i].S->z;
        float siny,cosy;
        if(l!=0){
            siny=sqrt((x-Sx)*(x-Sx)+(z-Sz)*(z-Sz))/S->korona[lvl-1].l;
            cosy=(y-Sy)/S->korona[lvl-1].l;
        }
        //else {siny=0;cosy=1;}
        float cosx,sinx;
        float co=cos(S->angle);
        float si=sin(S->angle);
        if(sqrt((x-Sx)*(x-Sx)+(z-Sz)*(z-Sz))==0){cosx=1;sinx=0;}
        else {
            cosx=(Sx-x)/sqrt((x-Sx)*(x-Sx)+(z-Sz)*(z-Sz));
            sinx=(z-Sz)/sqrt((x-Sx)*(x-Sx)+(z-Sz)*(z-Sz));
        }
        float lng=S->ratio*this->l;
        for(int j=0;j<S->amount;j++){
            float a=lng*co*cos(360.0f/S->amount*j*rad)*cosy-lng*si*siny;
            float b=lng*co*cos(360.0f/S->amount*j*rad)*siny+lng*si*cosy;
            float c=lng*co*sin(360.0f/S->amount*j*rad);
            sticks.push_back(Stick(&(S->korona[lvl-1].sticks[i]),
                                                    c*sinx+a*cosx+S->korona[lvl-1].sticks[i].x,
                                                    b+S->korona[lvl-1].sticks[i].y,
                                                    c*cosx-a*sinx+S->korona[lvl-1].sticks[i].z));
        }
    }

}
```

Im working on it at least few hours. I'm tired

**EDIT:**Ok, i did it. Some of the calculations were wrong. :/

Comment: What's the value of `i` when it does that? Does it end up going out of bounds?

Comment: @chris, I'm guessing you're pushing the first element which then refers to the -1'th element, and that the vector (unchecked) returns 0 for that.

Comment: "i" is between 1 and 20

Comment: What happens when yoyu run under the debugger - it should stop on the exception - also you should be able to tell us exactly which i it fails on

Comment: It throws only that. But thats definitely problem with a vector or something in it. But i checked and it crashes at the begining, that means when i is equal to 1;

So it can be something in constructor wrong

*EDIT:I cheched it, i cant declare Level using this constructor. Whats wrong in it.*